# Demonstrate that $f$ is constant.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function differentiable that:

a) $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

b) $\dfrac{df}{dy}(x,y)=0$ in all points.

Demonstrate that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Condition (b) implies that for any **fixed** $x$, the function $f(x,y)$ is independent of $y$.  So for all $y$ it has value $c(x)$, where $c(x)$ is a function of $x$ only.

Condition (a) then says that $c(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* For fixed $x$ consider $g(y):=f(x,y)$. Then $g(0)=0$ and $g'(y)=0$ for all $y$.

Answer (score 1):

From b), $f(x,y) = A + B x = f(x,0)$ for some constants $A$ and $B$.  But $f(x,0)=0 \: \forall x$, which means $A=0$ and $B=0$, which  means is $f$ is zero identically.